# Is there any Frame work to write J units for JSF Managed Beans

Tags: jsf-2, junit

Is there any Frame work to write J units for JSF Managed  Beans.

I am getting Null pointer Exception when I am trying to test the method which Contians the code as following.

```
FacesContext  context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
myBean =(MyBean)context.getApplication.evaluteExpressionGet(context,#{myBean},MyBean.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't already tried it, but there is a framework called JSFUnit published by JBoss.org, perhaps you will give it a try?!

http://www.jboss.org/jsfunit/